# Animating/moving a button in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm working in Android studio and I'm trying to animate a button from off screen to a position on screen as soon as the app starts(without any clicks).  Does anyone know of a way to do this?  I'm fairly new to Android studio so I'm familiar with the basics but not much more than that, thank you in advance.

Comment: To be more specific I'm trying to move the button from the bottom off screen to a position about 1/4 of the way up the screen centered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use translation animation for it. First create this xml animation file in `/res/anim/anim_translate.xml` folder:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<translate
   android:fromXDelta="0"
   android:toXDelta="100%p"
   android:duration="500"
   android:repeatCount="1"
   android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
</set>
```

Then set it to your button:

```
   final Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_translate);
    yourButton.startAnimation(animTranslate);
```

You can modify it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

It may gives to you a clue:

```
        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
        LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rl.setLayoutParams(params);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("AABBBCCC");
        LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        button.setLayoutParams(params1);
        rl.addView(button);
```